# Получение кода ветки на удаленном сервере

Tags: git, git-checkout

Я пытаюсь получить код из ветки удаленного репозитория:

Кто-то отправил в репозиторий ветку с названием `test` с помощью `git push origin test`. Я могу видеть ветку при помощи `git branch -r`, но как мне получить эту ветку?

- `git checkout test` не работает.
- `git checkout origin/test` что-то делает, но `git branch` возвращает `* (no branch)`. Я нахожусь на «no branch».

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[Checkout remote Git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/) » [@Juri Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179467/).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Ответ

Перед тем, как начать работу над удалённой веткой локально, необходимо получить её (fetch). Чтобы получить ветку, необходимо сделать следующее:

```
git fetch origin
```

Эта команда обновит все удалённые ветки. Вы сможете видеть все ветки, которые можно получить:

```
git branch -v -a
```

Имея список всех веток удалённого сервера, вы можете получить код необходимой ветки для редактирования, и у вас появится её локальная рабочая копия:

```
git checkout -b test origin/test
```

### Дополнение

В современном Git (>= [1.6.6](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.6.txt)), достаточно

```
git checkout test
```

(Обратите внимание, что `test` – это не `origin/test`.) чтобы выполнить волшебную операцию [«делай то, что я имею в виду»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F#DWIM) и создать локальную ветку `test`, которая будет иметь имя `origin/test` на удаленном сервере.

Таким образом, в версиях Git ≥ 1.6.6, достаточно следующего:

```
git fetch
git checkout test
```

Помните, что `git checkout test` *НЕ* будет работать в современном git при использовании сразу нескольких удалённых репозиториев. В этом случае воспользуйтесь `git checkout -b test remote-name/test`.

---

Строка `* (no branch)` в выдаче `git branch` означает, что вы находитесь в безымянной ветке, в так называемом состоянии «detached HEAD» (HEAD указывает непосредственно на коммит и не является символической ссылкой на какую-либо ветку). Если в этой безымянной ветке вы произвели несколько коммитов, вы всегда можете создать локальную ветку вне текущего коммита:

```
git checkout -b test HEAD
```

<sub>На основе [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783426/564240) [@hallski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214090/hallski) и [отвеа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1787014/564240) [@Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность создать локальную ветку на основе удалённой с её отслеживанием и идентичным именем с помощью команды **`git checkout --track [уд.репозитрий/уд.ветка]`**